# How do I get the last value in a string separated by commas?

Tags: swift, csv, swift3

I have this string

```
let data = 123,456,7,8,9,10
```

I want to extract the last value separated by a "," which in this case would  be 10, and its not necessarily a two digit value.

I tried this:

```
var data = 123,456,7,8,9,10
data = data.last!
```

Comment: You must have tried *something* ... don't hesitate to show your attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String method `data.components(separatedBy:)`

```
let data = "123,456,7,8,9,10"
let lastComponent = data.components(separatedBy: ",").last
print(lastComponent)
```